# An array that takes the size depending on what I enter

Tags: java, arrays

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Singleton{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter number of students: ");
        int number = input.nextInt();
        String names[] = new String[number];
        for(int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++){
            System.out.print("Enter name: ");
            names[counter] = input.nextLine();
            names[counter] = names[counter].toLowerCase();
        }
        int grades[] = new int[names.length];
        int count = 0;
        for(String x: names){
            System.out.print(x + "'s grade: ");
            grades[count] = input.nextInt();
            count++;
        }
        count = 0;
        for(String x: names){
            System.out.println(x + "'s grade is " + grades[count] + ".");
            count++;
        }
    }
}
```

can you help me to get something so I can put any number of values in the array without asking how many students there are?

Comment: Are you able to use an ArrayList? [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: I am new so I don't know how to use them so can you tell me how if they can help me ?

Comment: stop using arrays.  start using Collections (for example, LinkedList).

Comment: I will try to learn those you said (arraylists and collections).

Comment: It's too early to ask questions on SO, of you're not halfway through a beginner's Java book.

Comment: So can you tell me where to learn if I can't learn like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array that you can add a variable number of elements to you could use an ArrayList. i.e.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++){
        System.out.print("Enter name: ");
        names.add(input.nextLine());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Java has fixed length array and it is not possible to change size of array dynamically. To do what you need there is  java.util.ArrayList class.

*(look at Reginol_Blindhop's answer. Regardless is it ArrayList or LinkedList code is the same).*

But if you need array you can create new array with +1 size for every input, copy previous values there and put new into last element. To do that there is System.arraycopy method.

code may look like:

```
         String[] names = new String[1];

         for(int counter = 0; counter < 100; counter++){
                System.out.print("Enter name: ");
                String nextName = input.nextLine();

                String[] tempNames = new String[names.length + 1];
                System.arraycopy(names, 0, tempNames, 0, names.length);
                tempNames[names.length] = nextName;
                names = tempNames;
         }
```

PS. Of course for any solution it is better to use `while` loop and check if user finishes input by putting something special like "exit", "end", "bye", ":q" or whatever you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a List for something like this, not an array. As a general rule of thumb, when you don't know how many elements you will add to an array before hand, use a List instead. Most would probably tackle this problem by using an ArrayList.